# FreeImage: how to read and write image with EXIF?

Tags: c++, image, freeimage

Did not find the documentation. Can anyone give an example how to read image, replace data (from my buffer uchar[n][m]) and write image with EXIF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the documentataion does not help you, it is always worth looking at the examples and the unit tests. There is a program in the examples directory that shows the EXIF information, it seems to be a good starting point.

https://github.com/imazen/freeimage/blob/171744f4bc384f8872fd9437b23bbb5d54563253/Examples/Generic/ShowMetadata.cpp